# Documenting OData operators using Swagger

Tags: rest, odata, swagger, swagger-2.0

We are developing some new APIs and will be using OData for providing filters. We support multiple operators like eq, ne, and, not, contains, startwith, endswith, etc.
For existing APIs, we are using Swagger for documentation. These APIs have simple query parameters and don't support any operators.

For the new APIs, I want to know is there any way we can document OData operators using Swagger.

Sample queries with new APIs:

```
GET /users?filters=(firstName eq SAM) and (age le 35)
GET /users?filters=(firstName eq SAM) and (age le 35) or (contains(lastName, 'Tom'))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Referencing query parameters in the spec are allowed under parameters field.
You would add the type of parameter as query, and can add additional notes under description

```
paths:
  /users:
    get:
      summary: Gets a user by ID.
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: firstName
          type: string
          description: first name of user
```

See https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-parameters/ for more information

Comment: Yes, that is one way but I was keeping it as the last resort. I wanted to know if there is any built-in support in swagger to specify supported operators of a `filter` parameter instead of specifying in the description.